# How to show different preloader gif based on different ajax calls?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I am currently using a preloader gif for my ajax calls with this code:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    var position = $('#parentDiv').position();
    position.left += (($('#parentDiv').width() / 2) - ($('#bigPreloader').width() / 2));
    position.top += (($('#parentDiv').height() / 2) - ($('#bigPreloader').height() / 2));
    $('#bigPreloader').css(position).show();
    $('#bigPreloader').show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    $('#bigPreloader').hide();
});
```

In the above code, #parentDiv takes up the majority of the page, and the preloader is 250x250 pixels and is centered in #parentDiv.

This works fine, but I have just added some additional ajax calls that are associated with specific inputs, instead of the whole page. I have a small preloader (14x14 pixels) that I plan to put inside the appropriate input itself.

Is there a way inside ajaxStart to determine which ajax call was made? Or is there a way to have multiple ajaxStarts linked to specific elements?

**SOLUTION**

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, jqxhr, settings) {
    if (settings.url.indexOf('LoadInputData') == -1) {
        var position = $('#parentDiv').position();
        position.left += (($('#parentDiv').width() / 2) - ($('#bigPreloader').width() / 2));
        position.top += (($('#parentDiv').height() / 2) - ($('#bigPreloader').height() / 2));
        $('#bigPreloader').css(position).show();
        $('#bigPreloader').show();
    } else {
        $('#inputLoad').removeClass('notActive').addClass('isActive');
    }
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    if ($('#bigPreloader').is(':visible')) {
        $('#bigPreloader').hide();
    } else {
        $('#inputLoad').removeClass('isActive').addClass('notActive');
    }
});
```

Comment: can we see some code on fiddle? Probably making some minor changes to your url like **adding querystring** (url+"?biggerpreloader"/ url+"?smallerLoader") may help you do the same.These should be decided by the caller method and **depending on the url querystring you load the preloader.**

Comment: I'm not sure how to emulate an ajax call inside jsfiddle. I was hoping that there was a parameter I could use inside the function call from .ajaxStart, but there doesn't seem to be one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .ajaxStart() will only fire if all other calls have finished. If no requests are in progress it then fires the code in ajaxStart. So if you are using asynchronous requests this method wouldn't be of much help except if all the previous requests have finished running.

To solve your question I would suggest using the [.ajaxSend()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/) method instead. This method fires every time, just before a request is about to be sent out. So it does almost the same thing as .ajaxStart(). To differentiate between requests you can use the parameters passed to the handler function. There are several things you could test for, but probably easiest to just go for the URL, like so:

Ex from jQuery docs:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, jqxhr, settings) {
    if ( settings.url == "ajax/test.html" ) { //Test by URL
        //Do your specific pre-loader stuff here
    }
});
```

You can also set the context in your specific request. Doing this will set the `$(this)` selector to the context you specified, thus allowing you to separate the logic from the DOM as well. This way you can have a single function with the loader set up, that gets posted on the element you set in the context.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html",
    context: document.body
}).done(function() {
    $(this).addClass("done"); //$(this) is the document.body or could be the element you want to put your specific loader in.
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! I added a class to both preloaders .isPreloader so I could just hide both from ajaxStart without concern for which one was displayed. Thanks!